# How to get all issues from Test Cycle using ZAPI rest api call

Tags: rest, jira, jira-zephyr

I have created a Project in JIRA and created issues then I have created a Test Cycle using Zephyr plugin and added issues to the cycle. Now i want get all the issues I have added in Test Cycle using Rest call. I have tried below:
I did a JIRA Search for all the projects and got my project id :
GET -http://jira.hk.hsbc/rest/api/latest/project = 583215

then I looked for Test Cycles available in my project by using my project ID

GET - http://jira.hk.hsbc/rest/api/latest/project/21008/versions

then i did a search for cycles present in version using version id and project id
GET - http://jira.hk.hsbc/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=21008&versionId=36325

here i got cycle ids.

Now i want to do search for all the issues in one Cycle using cycle id but I am not able to find anything to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once I got my ProjectID , VersionID and CycleID I did a get 
GET :http://jira.hk.hsbc/rest/zapi/latest/execution?projectId=" + projectId + "&versionId=" + versionId + "&cycleId=" + cycleId;
This returns all my Issues and its information.
Then from the JSon object i retrived my IssueId , Key, ExeID etc.

Comment: Is there anyway we can get the details from multiple cycle Ids at the time

Answer (score 0):

You get all test cycles id's using this API.

```
https://[jira link]/rest/zapi/latest/cycle?projectId=[projectid]&versionId=[versionid]
```